# Change of format when converting byte array to String

Tags: java, mime

With reference to this post [Why are the lengths different when converting a byte array to a String and then back to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010478/why-are-the-lengths-different-when-converting-a-byte-array-to-a-string-and-then-b)

I understand that changing a byte array containing binary data by doing this

```
 String s = new String(bytes);
```

might cause the format of the binary data to change because it creates a string using the default encoding which may convert certain binary characters to unknown characters like "?" and if you convert it back to a byte array it will be wrong.

Currently I have a mime in a ByteArrayInputStream due to mime in mime which looks like this

```
--boundary
//content type, id, etc...
//empty line
//Binary Data
--boundary--
```

How do extract the Binary data from the Inputstream and convert it to Base64 if I cannot convert the byte array to a string in the first place? I was thinking of using the boundary to split the Sting converted from the Bytearrayinputstream, but doing so will mess up the Binary data even before I want to encode it to Base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you have an "empty line" in middle of the bytes (assuming 0x13 or 0x10 byte value), so just seek that byte and you can partition the original byte array.  The first part can be simply mapped to String and for the binary data, you now have offset, length, and byte data and that is all you need.

Comment: Thanks alphazero, that was the best suggestion that got me thinking! I read the array byte by byte and converted it to a String when it hit a LF+CR. When it was an empty String when converted as a byte array, I copied all the bytes into another array and stopped when it hit the boundary. I then truncated the bytearray with the length of the boundary +4 due to the additional two LF+CR behind. Is it safe to conclude that if you have a mix of binary data and text in a file, the only way to manipulate it is at the byte level if you want to maintain the binary integrity?

Comment: As far as I know.  If you have a mix of 'data types' -- meaning distinct mappings between byte patterns and type semantics e.g. UTF-8 -- in a contiguous byte block (memory or file, what's the diff?) you will naturally need to first partition that super block into a set of mini-blocks of uniform data semantics.  So, parse you must.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely convert binary to a String if you present the correct encoding of the String in the binary data! If you know your binary contains a String in ISO8859-1, just do

```
new String(byteArray,"ISO8859-1")
```

and nothing gets lost. And for your information: Base64-Encoded Strings only contains ASCII characters, which are the same in UTF-8 and all typical Windows- and ISO-Encodings, so you won't have any problems with either of them.

Comment: There is some sorcery involved - there is binary data in the message. The contents are not Base64 encoded.

Comment: That's where the fun starts. The client does not send the encoding in the HTTP header. I have a feeling that the parsers in the market, do this work in some manner, but I don't know how.

Comment: An earlier post I did shows that converting the inputstream into a byte array then writing into the file retains the format as I can see the full jpeg image from the binary if I strip everything else except the binary data, saving the file as a.jpg extension, then viewing it. But when the byte array becomes a string with some sort of encoding everything is messed up.